# Phonegap Local Notification Plugin for Android

Tags: android, cordova, uilocalnotification, statusbar

I'm working on a "Reminders" application on Android using Phonegap[Cordova 2.2].

The user enters a specific date for his reminder and I'm supposed to notify him on time.

I used this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification) to Just show a notification in the status bar & they are working fine.

But I want the notifications to show at specific times. Is there some method to do it ?

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification) that's supposed to do what I want but it's not working, it shows errors at :

```
import com.phonegap.api.Plugin;
import com.phonegap.api.PluginResult;
```

The import com.phonegap.api.Plugin cannot be resolved

So, how can I fix this error ? I know it might be easy, but I never made native Android Apps before so I'm kind of confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a difference between 2.0.0 and 2.2.0, and like the plugin needs updating.

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;
```

This should give you a jumping off point:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android

Answer (score 1):

For the new Phonegap Release you must also change some stuff:

1. The LocalNotification class must "extends CordovaPlugin" now
2. Import classes like eomer says
3. The execute method of LocalNotification.java must return a boolean now
4. Change all return arguments that are affected (from PluginResult) to boolean of your choice
5. Get the context in a new way `ctx = this.cordova.getActivity();` and give it the ...AlarmHelper(ctx)