# Alarm Clock like script for my cordova 2.7.0 android project

Tags: android, cordova, alarm, localnotification

I'm trying to build an android app by using phonegap.

I need to put a reminder into my app which will notificate the user at any time of the day.

I have tried to intagrate this plug-in; https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification

But since i use cordova 2.7.0 it does not work on my project.

In this link ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14307498/2386488 ) Sorcerer has given a way to fix the plug in but i could not apply it well.

Do you have any knowledge about, how can i add an alarm clock like specification into my application?

Thank you!

Comment: I would try to use that pre-existing plugin; what errors are you getting when you say you "could not apply it well?"

Answer (score 0):

This one is maintained and works for 2.7, with branches below that.

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications

That said this one is for IOS only as far as I can tell.